# How to make dynamic value in IDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic

I have a class that uses the Dictionary. It has a string key and object value:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        DynamicProperties.Add("Person", this.Person);
    }

    public IPerson Person { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

As you can see I have IPerson interface property in class and I am adding this in Dictionary. Student and Teacher classes are implementing this interface:

```
public interface IPerson
{

}

public class Student : IPerson
{

}

public class Teacher : IPerson
{

}
```

I want to get the current value of this dictonary by key. Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myclass = new MyClass();
        myclass.Person = new Student();
        var studentFromDictionary = myclass.DynamicProperties["Person"]; // It should be Student
        myclass.Person = new Teacher();
        var teacherFromDictionary = myclass.DynamicProperties["Person"]; // It should be Teacher
    }
```

How can I do this? (I can use the only dictionary that implements IDictionary)

Comment: under each key in dictionary may be only one object, so you simply can't story `Student` and `Teacher` instances under the same `"Person"` key

Comment: Also, your constructor set `"Person"` to `null`. Also, changing `myclass.Person` doesn't affect your `myclass.DynamicProperties`

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, That's why I am looking for the solution

Comment: @vasily.sib it will no affect even if "Person" was not set to null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom logic in your getters and setters, so expand your `Person` property to explicit implementation with backing field and manage dictionary there:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        private IPerson _person;

        public MyClass()
        {
            DynamicProperties.Add("Person", this.Person);
        }

        public IPerson Person
        {
            get
            {
                return _person;
            }
            set
            {
                DynamicProperties["Person"] = value;
                _person = value;
            }
        }

        public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
```

**UPD**

Also you can make your `MyClass` just implement `IDictionary` like this so you will not need the `DynamicProperties` property:

```
public class MyClass : IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }

    // can be build via reflection
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<MyClass, object>> _dic = new Dictionary<string, Func<MyClass, object>>
    {
        {nameof(MyClass.Prop), (Func<MyClass, object>)(mc => mc.Prop)}      
    };

    public object this[string key] => _dic[key](this);

    public IEnumerable<string> Keys => _dic.Keys;

    public IEnumerable<object> Values => _dic.Values.Select(func => func(this));

    public int Count => _dic.Count;

    public bool ContainsKey(string key) => _dic.ContainsKey(key);

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _dic.Select(kvp => KeyValuePair.Create(kvp.Key, kvp.Value(this))).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out object value)
    {
        value = null;
        if(_dic.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            value = this[key];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var prop = new MyClass() {Prop = "Test"}["Prop"]; // prop = "Test"
```